# C# as a scripting language in a Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, scripting, roslyn

I need to be able to execute some small scripts inside my Xamarin Forms C# application, and I was excited to see the 'Roslyn' technology that is implemented in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis libraries.  But I cannot get the scripting to work.  Notice I am trying to run a script inside my application, nothing to do with Visual Studio.  I'm hesitant to generate an external DLL and somehow call it from my application, but will do it if I have to.

I am able to parse functions (using CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText) but when I try to create the smallest possible script ("1 + 2") it throws an exception every time:

```
Exception TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AppContext' threw an exception.
Source: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting
   Stack trace:   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Hosting.RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver.ResolveTrustedPlatformAssemblyCore (System.String name, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReferenceProperties properties) [0x00007] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Hosting/Resolvers/RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver.cs:169 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Hosting.RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver.ResolveReference (System.String reference, System.String baseFilePath, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReferenceProperties properties) [0x000d0] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Hosting/Resolvers/RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver.cs:154 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.GetReferencesForCompilation (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag diagnostics, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference languageRuntimeReferenceOpt) [0x000ac] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:276 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScriptCompiler.CreateSubmission (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script script) [0x00021] in /_/src/Scripting/CSharp/CSharpScriptCompiler.cs:38 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script.GetCompilation () [0x00008] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:142 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1[T].GetExecutor (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00008] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:359 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1[T].RunAsync (System.Object globals, System.Func`2[T,TResult] catchException, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0001b] in /_/src/Scripting/Core/Script.cs:463 
   at MyCompany.MyApp.AppViewModel.TryScript () [0x002d3] in C:\Workspace\Mobile\Apps\MyApp\MyApp\AppViewModel.cs:1067 
Exception ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   Parameter name: type
   Source: mscorlib
   Stack trace:   at System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo (System.Type type) [0x00009] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.14.0.114/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Reflection/IntrospectionExtensions.cs:14 
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CoreClrShim+AppContext..cctor () [0x0000f] in /_/src/Compilers/Shared/CoreClrShim.cs:28
```

There are a lot of people trying to do this same thing and having problems:

- [This site](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23537) suggests adding a reference to mscorlib but that
  didn't help.
- [This site](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24442) doesn't have any suggestions
- [This site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025921/xamarin-android-runtime-c-sharp-compilation) has no suggestions
- Nothing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212599/how-to-execute-script-with-xamarin-forms-on-android)
- Nobody replied to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473916/build-a-xamarin-project-via-roslyn-and-get-the-assembly)
- My favorite is [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16211) where the person with the problem is told that Roslyn doesn't work with .NET Core and it's .NET Core's fault.

Here's what I've got right now in my application, as an attempt to execute the very simple script "1+2":

```
using (var loader = new InteractiveAssemblyLoader())
{
   loader.RegisterDependency(typeof(object).Assembly);
   loader.RegisterDependency(typeof(AppContext).Assembly);
   loader.RegisterDependency(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly);
   var script = CSharpScript.Create<int>("1 + 2", assemblyLoader: loader);
   var result = await script.RunAsync();
   Debug.WriteLine("   Script returned " + result);
}
```

Comment: please note that Apple explicitly prohibits dynamic code in iOS apps

Comment: We don't use the App Store so that's not a concern for us.

Comment: just a suggestion.... use a simpler c# script until you get it working. once its working, use the script above. Something like declare an integer, assign to it.

Comment: I have edited my post to make it clear that the code above is what I have in my application, as an attempt to execute the script "1+2"

Comment: ah, i misread. i assumed your script was the whole using block.

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a better story for Roslyn here, you can consider using the [Mono Evaluator](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.CSharp.Evaluator) for dynamic code evaluation in a Xamarin.Forms iOS or Android app.

1. Add a reference to `Mono.CSharp.dll`
2. Prepare the evaluator

```
var cc = new CompilerContext(new CompilerSettings(), new ReportPrinter())
var evaluator = new Evaluator(cc);

// add assembly references
evaluator.ReferenceAssembly(..);
```

3. Evaluate scripts

```
evaluator.Evaluate("1 + 1", out var result, out _);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 2

evaluator.Run("public class NewClass { public string HelloWorld => \"Hello World\"; }");
evaluator.Evaluate("new NewClass().HelloWorld", out result, out _);
Console.WriteLine(result); // "Hello World"
```

On the iOS simulator, you'll need the `--enable-repl` mtouch flag. 
On an iOS device, you need the `--interpreter` flag, and to build using a version of Xamarin.iOS/Mono that has `Reflection.Emit` enabled. I'm not sure if stable builds are shipping with RefEmit enabled currently, but I have previously written about baking your own version with it in [here](https://ryandavis.io/how-to-have-your-ios-13-preview-cake-and-emit-it-too). If you do decide that dynamically loading externally generated assemblies is adequate, you can definitely get away with just using the `--interpreter` flag today with any recent Xamarin.iOS builds.

Note that (in my experience) the C# language features supported by the evaluator lag that of the Roslyn equivalent, avoiding features introduced after C# 6 is most reliable.